# Ruby on Rails / MVC - Splitting Views for different user levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a Rails application which handles hotel room reservations. I would like an admin to see all reservations and specific users to only see their reservations. Is the 'proper' way of doing this:

1. Create a new action for each user in the reservation controller

   *OR*
2. Put an if statement in the index action, deciding whether to return all reservations or only those for a user id sent by parameter

I have it set up and working the second way but I'm not sure this is the correct way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by having a single view, which is populated by the appropriate collection of reservations. For an admin this would be all reservations, but for a regular user the collection would only contain their bookings.

This then requires a single if statement in the controller to ascertain the appropriate reservations:

```
if user.is_admin?
  @reservations = Reservation.all
else
  @reservations = user.reservations
end
```

The above code assumes that you've setup an appropriate relationship between a user and their reservations, but you get the idea.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, I hadn't thought of doing it this way. Is there anyway it could be adapted to show reservations for certain rooms too?

Comment: I think an elsif could be added to check if a room_id parameter had been passed in, then display reservations for that room only. Thanks for your help and securing my thoughts that it is 'ok' to use if statements rather than new actions.

Comment: The code would be very similar assuming that each room is aware of its reservations. The admin condition would read room.reservations and the non-admin condition would be room.reservations.where('user_id = ?',user.id).